# The columns in table do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

How does one work around the issue of not matching an existig primary key or unique constraint when creating a FK in SSMS?

---

I have two tables namely : `user` and `firstdb` where both fields have the same datatype. In `user` table I have two primary keys, and in the foreign key table I have one field which I want to make it the target of a foreign key.

[image]

[image]

I tried to have one field as a primary key in the user table, the relationship worked fine at that time but once I set the second field to primary it forces me to delete the existing relationship for some reason.
I tried to create a relationship like this in MySQL, it worked fine with me, but it doesn't work.

Comment: "In user table I have two primary keys".  *Primary* key means there is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a profound misunderstand of what a *primary* key is.  A primary key (singular) is one or more columns that uniquely identify each row (and none of the columns are `NULL`).  When you click "primary key" by two columns, you are generating a *composite* primary key.

Foreign key references need to be to the *complete* primary key.  If you have a composite primary key, you need a composite foreign key.

Having single column foreign key references is one reason why the best type of primary key is an identity column.  I am guessing that `userid` is such a column.

If you want `uEmailId` to be unique and non-NULL, then define it as unique and non-NULL.  However, don't add it to the primary key!

Comment: I get it now, its working fine thanks for your help.